# Extracting H.264 NAL Units from a MPEG transport stream?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avfoundation, video-toolbox

How can I extract the H.264 NAL units from an MPEG Transport Stream on the iOS platform?  Is there anything in the VideoToolbox or AVFoundation that can help me with this?  Do I have to parse the stream myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to do the TS demuxing and parsing yourself. See this video, if you haven't already:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-513/